# .bat file for searching through large text files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a bat file that looks through large text files that are in the same folder, and dumps strings from what you search. It can search through multiple files, however if there are 2 text files that have what you are searching for, they don't show as separate strings in the output. If someone can find a fix that, it would be awesome

```
@echo off
title Dumper
color 2
:start
cls
set input=
set /p input= Name To Dump :
findstr /s /i "%input%" *.*  > "%input%_dump.txt"
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo Dumped All Occurrences For %input% Into %input%_dump.txt
) else (
echo No Data Found
timeout /t 5000
goto start
)
timeout /t 5000
cls
goto start
```

http://pastebin.com/MkhpzFu1

Here is the output I get if I have 2 text files that say test

1.txt:test2.txt:test

Here is the output if I have 1 text file with "test" written twice (the output is how it should look when searching through 2 text files as I did above)

1.txt:test
1.txt:test

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: It is linked in pastebin

Comment: And it's not in your question why? I don't have any relationship with Pastebin. Why would I lose your question to see a new page.

Comment: Maybe the two files have no ANSI coding?

Comment: Try `findstr /I /s /c:"%input%" *.*` as you don't specify how to search the search in taken to be a RegExp. That may or may not matter. See `Findstr /?`.

Comment: That still resulted with the same output. Try making the bat and run it in a folder with 2 text files. (in both text files write "test") Run the bat and search for "test" and check the output, then you can see the problem

Comment: `C:\Users\user>findstr /I /s /c:"fred" *.asc` gives two lines - `test.asc:fred` and `test1.asc:fred`.

Comment: try with .txt files

Comment: The script I attached does everything it is supposed to do if there is one text file that it searches through. Having more than 1 text file makes the output a little untidy which is what I am trying to fix

Comment: asc are text files.

Comment: what do you mean with `untidy`? What exactly is wrong with the output? Maybe give an example of a) what you get and b) what you *want* to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `untidy` means "I don't like to have the filenames", replace

```
findstr /s /i "%input%" *.*  > "%input%_dump.txt"
```

with

```
type *.* 2>nul | findstr /s /i "%input%" > "%input%_dump.txt"
```

**EDIT**

with the additional info (example output), I tried to reproduce your symptom.

Your problem probably is: your search string in the first file is at the last line, and there is no line feed (end of line) at this line. There is no "nice" way to handle this, but the following should do (although without the filenames):

```
for %%a in (*.txt) do type %%a|findstr "hello"
```

As an alternative, you can add a linefeed to each file before running  `findstr` (may or may not be an option for you):

```
for %%a in (*.txt) do echo/>>%%a
findstr /s /i "%input%" *.txt  > "%input%_dump.txt"
```

Comment: The filenames are fine, but try running it with 2 files that say the same thing. They will show up on the same line

Comment: never seen such a behaviour. Can you provide an example output? (don't paste it into a comment, edit your question instead)

Comment: I added it at the end of the question for you

Comment: I have very little knowledge on bat files so it would be great if you could send what you have in the code I posted. Also the bat file didn't only work for .txt, it worked for any file. Do I just change *.txt to *.* ? Lastly, the bottom solution worked, but would it make the process longer when searching through large files?

Comment: yes, change `*.txt` to `*.*`. Adding an empty line to each file will be quite fast and you won't notice any time difference with `findstr`.

Comment: sorry for the question spam, but I have one last question before I mark your answer as right. The     type *.* 2>nul |       command also worked, will this slow down the speed? And what does it mean? Thanks again

Comment: `2>nul` redirects error output to nirvana (`type` uses error output for displaying the filenames, which you don't want here). This will not slow down anything. `|` pipes the output of `type` to the next command (`findstr`). This also should not have a big performance impact.

Answer (score 1):

I quickly modified this script : ***["Local_Search_Engine.bat"](http://pastebin.com/ADdjPEfH)***  just to search only on `*.txt` files

So give a try and tell me the results :

***Searching_in_txt_files.bat***

```dos
@ECHO OFF
Title Scan a folder and Search a string in multi-text-files by (c) Hackoo 2016
mode con cols=75 lines=2
Call :init
Call :inputbox "Please enter something to search :" "Search a string in multi-files by (c) Hackoo 2016"
If  "%input%" == ""  Color 0C & (
    echo(
    echo           You must enter a string to continue with this program 
    pause>nul & exit
) else (
    Call :Browse4Folder "Choose source folder to scan for %input%" "c:\scripts"
)
::******************************************************************************************
Set "ROOT=%Location%"
::Does string have a trailing back slash ? if so we remove it !
IF %ROOT:~-1%==\ SET ROOT=%ROOT:~0,-1%
Set "NewFolder2Copy=%userprofile%\Desktop\Searching_%input%_Files"
SET "EXT=txt"
SET "Count=0"
set "Word2Search=%input%"
Set "LogFile=%~dp0%~n0_%Word2Search%.txt"
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
REM Iterates throw the files on this current folder and its subfolders.
REM And Populate the array with existent files in this folder and its subfolders
For %%a in (%EXT%) Do ( 
    Call :Scanning "%Word2Search%" "*.%%a" 
    Call :PS_Sub 'information' 10 '"Scanning now for """%Word2Search%""" on """*.%%a""" . . . "' "'Please wait. . . Scan is in progress on all """*.%%a""" . . .'" 'info' 5
    FOR /f "delims=" %%f IN ('dir /b /s "%ROOT%\*.%%a"') DO (
        ( find /I "%Word2Search%" "%%f" >nul 2>&1 ) && (
            SET /a "Count+=1"
            set "list[!Count!]=%%~nxf"
            set "listpath[!Count!]=%%~dpFf"
        )
    ) || (
            ( Call :Scanning "%Word2Search%" "%%~nxf" )
    )
)
::***************************************************************
:Display_Results
cls & color 0B
echo wscript.echo Len("%ROOT%"^) + 20 >"%tmp%\length.vbs"
for /f %%a in ('Cscript /nologo "%tmp%\length.vbs"') do ( set "cols=%%a")
If %cols% LSS 50 set /a cols=%cols% + 24
rem If %cols% LSS 50 set /a cols=%cols% + 15
set /a lines=%Count% + 12
Mode con cols=%cols% lines=%lines%
echo(
Call :color 0A " ------------------------------------------------" 1
ECHO   Folder : "%ROOT%"
Call :color 0A " ------------------------------------------------" 1
rem If Exist "%LogFile%" Del "%LogFile%"
rem Display array elements and save results into the LogFile
for /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do (
    echo [%%i] : !list[%%i]!
    echo [%%i] : !list[%%i]! -- "!listpath[%%i]!" >> "%LogFile%"     
)

(   
    ECHO.
    ECHO Total of [%EXT%] files(s^) : %Count% file(s^) that contains the string "%Word2Search%"
)>> "%LogFile%"
ECHO(
ECHO Total of [%EXT%] files(s) : %Count% file(s)
echo.
Call :color 0D "   Type the number of file that you want to explore" 1
echo(
Call :color 0C "     To save those files just hit 'S'" 1
set /p "Input="
For /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) Do (
    If "%INPUT%" EQU "%%i" (
        Call :Explorer "!listpath[%%i]!"
    )
    IF /I "%INPUT%"=="S" (
        Call :CopyFiles
    )
)   
Goto:Display_Results
::**************************************************************
:Scanning <Word> <file>
mode con cols=75 lines=3
Cls & Color 0E
echo(
echo         Scanning for the string "%~1" on "%~2" ...
goto :eof
::*************************************************************
:Explorer <file>
explorer.exe /e,/select,"%~1"
Goto :EOF
::*************************************************************
:MakeCopy <Source> <Target>
If Not Exist "%~2\" MD "%~2\"
Copy /Y "%~1" "%~2\"
goto :eof
::*************************************************************
:CopyFiles
cls
mode con cols=80 lines=20
for /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do (
    echo Copying "!list[%%i]!" "%NewFolder2Copy%\"
    Call :MakeCopy  "!listpath[%%i]!" "%NewFolder2Copy%">nul 2>&1 
)
Call :Explorer "%NewFolder2Copy%\"
Goto:Display_Results
::***************************************************************************
:InputBox
set "input="
set "heading=%~2"
set "message=%~1"
echo wscript.echo inputbox(WScript.Arguments(0),WScript.Arguments(1)) >"%temp%\input.vbs"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\input.vbs" "%message%" "%heading%"') do ( 
    set "input=%%a"
)
exit /b
::***************************************************************************
:PS_Sub $notifyicon $time $title $text $icon $Timeout
PowerShell  ^
  [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Windows.Forms') ^| Out-Null; ^
 [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Drawing') ^| Out-Null; ^
 $notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon; ^
  $notify.icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::%1; ^
  $notify.visible = $true; ^
  $notify.showballoontip(%2,%3,%4,%5); ^
  Start-Sleep -s %6; ^
  $notify.Dispose()
%End PowerShell%
exit /B
::****************************************************************************
:Browse4Folder
set Location=
set vbs="%temp%\_.vbs"
set cmd="%temp%\_.cmd"
for %%f in (%vbs% %cmd%) do if exist %%f del %%f
for %%g in ("vbs cmd") do if defined %%g set %%g=
(
    echo set shell=WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application"^) 
    echo set f=shell.BrowseForFolder(0,"%~1",0,"%~2"^) 
    echo if typename(f^)="Nothing" Then  
    echo wscript.echo "set Location=Dialog Cancelled" 
    echo WScript.Quit(1^)
    echo end if 
    echo set fs=f.Items(^):set fi=fs.Item(^) 
    echo p=fi.Path:wscript.echo "set Location=" ^& p
)>%vbs%
cscript //nologo %vbs% > %cmd%
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%cmd%) do %%a
for %%f in (%vbs% %cmd%) do if exist %%f del /f /q %%f
for %%g in ("vbs cmd") do if defined %%g set %%g=
goto :eof
::****************************************************************************
:init
prompt $g
for /F "delims=." %%a in ('"prompt $H. & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"
exit /b
::****************************************************************************
:color
set nL=%3
if not defined nL echo requires third argument & pause > nul & goto :eof
if %3 == 0 (
    <nul set /p ".=%bs%">%2 & findstr /v /a:%1 /r "^$" %2 nul & del %2 2>&1 & goto :eof
) else if %3 == 1 (
    echo %bs%>%2 & findstr /v /a:%1 /r "^$" %2 nul & del %2 2>&1 & goto :eof
)
exit /b
::***************************************************************************
```

Comment: That is a lot of code, and judging by your name I am slightly hesitant to run it

Comment: The script I attached does everything it is supposed to do if there is one text file that it searches through. Having more than 1 text file makes the output a little untidy which is what I am trying to fix

Comment: @JeremyM [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39888561/edit) your question and add what did you get as output result and what did you expect to get instead !

Comment: Dispite his name and needless complexity, it would be safe to run. Look at his points.

Comment: @JeremyM You are free to test or not my script ! and you judge just by my name to stay hesitant to run it or not ???? ==> Nice Behavior dude !